# Is there any reason why MCU changed the Snap to Blip

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, when Thanos snaps his fingers with the Infinity Stones, half the population vanishes.

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Banner snaps his fingers with the Infinity Stones & the vanished people are brought back. Later on, when Tony snaps his fingers, Thanos & his army vanishes.

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, the news & people refer to the Snap as the Blip.

Why did the MCU decide to officially call this event as the Blip?

I might be imagining but I think the Avengers referred to it as the Snap.

Comment: Keep in mind that the surviving half of the in-universe people (minus those who fought Thanos) would have had no idea of what caused the other half to disappear. The 'snap' was only apparent to those who saw it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Blip and Snap are different events as per Kevin Feige:

> "It came pretty fast. We always referred to it as the Blip, and then the public started referring to it as the Snap," explained Feige. "We think it's funny when high school kids just call this horrific, universe-changing event the Blip. We've narrowed it down to, the Snap is when everybody disappeared at the end of Infinity War. The Blip is when everybody returned at the end of Endgame… and that is how we have narrowed in on the definitions." - [comicbook.com](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/07/07/marvel-studios-kevin-feige-explains-difference-between-blip-snap/)

Comment: FWIW IW/EG never give the event a name, they only refer to the action of snapping fingers such as _"When Thanos snapped his fingers, Earth became ground zero for a power surge of ridiculously cosmic proportions"_.

Comment: Did Kevin Feige or anyone from the production, cast or Russo Brothers use Blip in any of their interviews after Infinity War Or Endgame was released?

Comment: @KharoBangdo can't find any such case

Comment: In the same interview, it was stated that "the blip" was the official name from the beginning, but people began to call it "the snap" before they could even mention it, so I guess they decide to save it for the SpiderMan movie

Comment: Wasn't there a preview for Spider-Man: Far from Home that had Nick Fury saying "The Snap tore a hole in the universe"?   That line may not have been used in the movie, though.

Comment: I always thought it was a bit odd that they took that finger-snapping thing literally.  I figured Thanos saying he could remove half of all life with a snap of his fingers was just implying that the Stones would give him that power and it would be _as simple as_ snapping his fingers.  The fact that merely possessing the Stones isn't enough and that you actually _do_ have to physically snap your fingers in order to use them is pretty silly to me.  (If for no other reason than there's undoubtedly countless species in the universe who don't necessarily have hands or fingers to snap...)

Comment: Why would someone want to call it blip? Snap sounds way cooler and correct to me. Snap is snap, it doesn't matter what it does in the end. Expending controversies unnecessarily

Comment: The way I interpret it is that "the snap" refers to Thanos' initial snap when he wipes out half the universe - a single moment in time.  "The blip" refers to the five year time span when half the universe was blipped out of existence.  The blip started at the snap.

Comment: Also, in universe, there's no reason that anyone would call it a snap.  We call it a snap because we saw Thanos snap his fingers, but everyone else just saw people disappear and come back, hence blip.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that the general public know exactly what happened during the blip. Steve Rogers casually mentions Thanos, but he goes completely unmentioned by anyone else outside of the Avengers. As such, I think it would be unlikely for the general public to call it the snap.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20blip) defines blip as

> an unexpected, minor, and typically temporary deviation from a general trend.

"The Blip" was an unexpected, temporary deviation. Everyone came back. Obviously it was far from minor, but I feel that a euphemism is appropriate.

Comment: I can't question the official statement but blip doesn't have the same weight as Snap or for that matter, any other word. Blip is an anomaly. They used it to refer to the event of people coming back is ok, but to use it to refer to people vanishing seems shallow. Don't know if you know this but check out The Leftovers, an unofficial MCU part between Infinity War & Endgame, where 2% of people vanish. They call it Sudden Departure. People will associate this event with God & choose some biblical term to refer to the Snap. Blip sounds ordinary

Comment: @KharoBangdo You are right that this implies ordinary. I think that this event was so huge that no word could describe it well. People are confused about what's going on, and hope it won't happen again. With little idea about what's going on, they call it the blip. As I stated, I believe this is a euphemism.